# Get sender name event handler

Tags: c#, eventargs

I hope the name gives justice to my question... So, I just started making a memory game, and there are 25 checkbox buttons which I am using to show the items.

I was wondering whether there was a way to tell from either the EventArgs or the Object what button it was sent from if each button used the same event handler.

```
private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkBox = Code which will determine what checkBox sent it.
        if (checkBox.Checked)
        { Box.ChangeState(checkBox, true); }
        else { Box.ChangeState(checkBox, false);}
    }
```

Comment: That's what the `sender` is, the thing that triggers the event.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible, but if you create your own subclass of `EventArgs` and pass it as a parameter instead, you could define the name of the method in there. But so far I haven't found a way to overwrite the standard signature.

Comment: Thanks @EvanTrimboli, didn't know if I was asking the question right.

Answer (score 18):

Try setting the `Name` attribute of each checkbox when defining them and then using `((CheckBox)sender).Name` to identify each individual checkbox.

Definition time:

```
CheckBox chbx1 = new CheckBox();
chbx1.Name = "chbx1";
chbx1.CheckedChanged += checkBox_CheckedChanged;
CheckBox chbx2 = new CheckBox();
chbx2.Name = "chbx2";
chbx2.CheckedChanged += checkBox_CheckedChanged;
CheckBox chbx3 = new CheckBox();
chbx3.Name = "chbx2";
chbx3.CheckedChanged += checkBox_CheckedChanged;
```

And

```
private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string chbxName = ((CheckBox)sender).Name;
        //Necessary code for identifying the CheckBox and following processes ...
        checkBox = Code which will determine what checkBox sent it.
        if (checkBox.Checked)
        { Box.ChangeState(checkBox, true); }
        else { Box.ChangeState(checkBox, false);}
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The sender object is actually the Control that initiated the event, you can cast it to the proper type to access all of its properties.  You can use the `Name` as stated or as I sometimes do is to use the `Tag` Property. But in this case just casting sender to a CheckBox should work.

```
private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)sender;
    if (cb.Checked)
    { Box.ChangeState(cb, true); }
    else { Box.ChangeState(cb, false); }
}
```